# is the size of buffered youtube video same as downloaded youtube video?

Tags: youtube

X = size of video content which is actually being buffered directly while seing videos on youtube .

Y = size of video being downloaded from youtube using different addons or plugins .

So is it that X is less than Y . If yes , than why is it so ??

Answer (score 0):

It could be depending on the encoding that is used in the download process for Y.

Also there are various qualities of video available for watching on youtube and the plugin/addons could use either highest or lowest quality.